# H2 database in tomcat environment throwing RuntimeException "unexpected code path" on select sequence.nextval

Tags: java, tomcat, h2

I am using H2 database h2-1.4.193 as datasource in tomcat.

This is my `server.xml` entry:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" 
    logAbandoned="true" 
    maxIdle="10" 
    maxOpenPreparedStatements="5" 
    maxTotal="50" 
    maxWaitMillis="10000" 
    name="jdbc/shopfloor_local" 
    password="***" poolPreparedStatements="false" 
    removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"      
    removeAbandonedTimeout="180" scope="Shareable" testWhileIdle="true"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="600000" type="javax.sql.DataSource"

    url="jdbc:h2:~/shopfloor;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=3"

    username="SA"
    validationQuery="select  1"/>
```

I use this datasource for both the DataSourceRealm and my application. In my application I execute a select on a sequence:

```
select aufgabenliste_seq.nextval
```

and then I get this error:

```
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: 
/**/conn3.setAutoCommit(false);
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: 
/**/PreparedStatement prep8 = conn3.prepareStatement("select    aufgabenliste_seq.nextval");
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: Plan       : calculate cost for plan    [SYSTEM_RANGE:0:org.h2.table.RangeTable@603d6c40]
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: Plan       :   for table filter SYSTEM_RANGE:0:org.h2.table.RangeTable@603d6c40
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: Table      :     potential plan item cost 1 index PUBLIC.RANGE_INDEX
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: Plan       :   best plan item cost 1 index PUBLIC.RANGE_INDEX
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: Plan       : plan cost 2
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: /**/ResultSet rs9 = prep8.executeQuery();
2016-12-23 00:46:03 lock: 1 exclusive write lock requesting for SYS
2016-12-23 00:46:03 lock: 1 exclusive write lock added for SYS
2016-12-23 00:46:03 lock: 1 exclusive write lock unlock SYS
2016-12-23 00:46:03 lock: 1 exclusive write lock requesting for SYS
2016-12-23 00:46:03 lock: 1 exclusive write lock added for SYS
2016-12-23 00:46:03 jdbc[3]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"
General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
select aufgabenliste_seq.nextval [50000-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:213)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:110)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:242)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:255)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.addLock(Session.java:842)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.doLock2(MVTable.java:254)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.doLock1(MVTable.java:202)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.lock(MVTable.java:167)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.lockMeta(Database.java:909)
...
...
```

I have debugged into the code. The Exception is thrown in Session class in Method `addLock()`:

```
    public void addLock(Table table) {
        if (SysProperties.CHECK) {
            if (locks.contains(table)) {
                DbException.throwInternalError();
            }
        }
        locks.add(table);
    }
```

The `table` object to be logged contains the table `SYS`.

Why is requesting the lock of `SYS` failing in this case? 
Should I provide additional parameters to the connection string?

See also [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/x2XoFP1G2l8)

Comment: Looks like a double lock of sys. Ask the developers, most likely a bug in h2.

Comment: Yes, I am in contact with the developers: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/x2XoFP1G2l8

Answer (score 0):

I found this article trying to repair a Confluence internal h2 database, getting this same error, and this worked for me. Here's a shell script as a [gist on my GitHub](https://gist.github.com/AlmostGosu/6220fbf8adb7f46044e4578f67f3a28e) with what I did - you'll have to adjust for your environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script has to be run as your confluence user or root
# Create a backup of, and attempt to restore a confluence h2 internal database

# Go home.
cd ~

# Stop confluence
/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/stop-confluence.sh
# Really though...
pgrep java | xargs kill

#create a good backup of your database files
mkdir -p ~/confluence-db-restore/originals
cp /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence/database/*.db ~/confluence-db-restore/originals

# create another good backup of your database files
tar -cvzf ~/confluence-db-restore/"$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')_h2db_backup.tar.gz" ~/confluence-db-restore/originals

# create a copy of your db to work from
cp ~/confluence-db-restore/originals/*.db ~/confluence-db-restore

# Create recovery SQL script
/opt/atlassian/confluence/jre/bin/java -cp \
/opt/atlassian/confluence/confluence/WEB-INF/lib/h2-*.jar \
org.h2.tools.Recover

# move working files and restore database
mkdir -p ~/confluence-db-restore/recovery
mv *.sql ~/confluence-db-restore/recovery
cd ~/confluence-db-restore/recovery
/opt/atlassian/confluence/jre/bin/java -cp \
/opt/atlassian/confluence/confluence/WEB-INF/lib/h2-*.jar \
org.h2.gools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:./h2db -user sa -script *.sql


################################################################################
# IMPORTANT THAT YOU MOVE THE RECOVERED DATABASE IF THE RESTORE WAS SUCCESSFUL #
# Uncomment this line to copy the restored database over your existing         #
################################################################################

# cp -f ~/confluence-db-restore/recovery/*.db /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence/database/
# chown -R confluence:confluence /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence

systemctl restart confluence
```